# How can I see which ASP.NET request is behind a running SQL query?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, iis

I'm watching my SQL Server 2008 box, and I see a query that's been running for a long time. I know it was kicked off by the webserver -- but I want to know which ASP.NET request is to blame. (That way I can see which user/IP is behind it.)

sys.dm_exec_requests gives me a session_ID for the query. How can I find out which ASP.NET request is waiting for a response from that session_ID?

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship unless you create it. Database call does not know anything about the ASP.NET session. The session id you mentioned is the SQL session.

Easiest solution is to add tracing with session info.

**UPDATE**
Tracing:

1) [Enable tracing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)

2) Trace start of calling database with the session id or user id

3) Trace end of calling database with the session id or user id. Calculate how long it took and trace that as well.

Comment: Can you explain how to add that kind of tracing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for debugging purposes, here is a hack that I have used in the past. The ConnectionString has an available string parameter named "Application." You can put whatever you want into that parameter and it will show up on the Activity Monitor in SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Sorry, I had to uncheck the "answer" box because I realized that while I could use the Application parameter to pass in a sessionID, it would prevent connection pooling from working -- every connection string would look a little different.